# Why is my for-loop not decrementing after i = 0? (need i to become negative to exit out of loop!)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Trying to solve this Easy LeetCode question using two ptrs. Values for m & n should be constant, and I'm not decrementing the value for i anywhere else. Why is my for-loop not decrementing after i = 0? Any ideas? TIA!

```
class Solution {
public void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {
    //Start filling nums1[] from the end instead
    //Will run in O(m+n) = nums1.length()
    int ptr1 = m-1, ptr2 = n-1;
    for(int i = m+n-1; i > -1; i--){
        //System.out.println("i = " + i);
        //System.out.println("ptr1 = " + ptr1 + "\tptr2 = " + ptr2);
        if(ptr2 < 0 || nums1[ptr1] > nums2[ptr2])
            nums1[i] = nums1[ptr1--];
        else
            nums1[i] = nums2[ptr2--];
        System.out.println("nums1[" + i + "] = " + nums1[i]);
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: The output you marked in red is from running the "Example 2" test and your code fails when running the "Example 3" test. You can verify that the for loop correctly exits by adding a `System.out.println("Done");` after the for loop.

Comment: I DID NOT NOTICE THAT, THANK YOU SO MUCH! ‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: LeetCode didn't let me know which TestCase(s) successfully ran. They need to update their UI imo, they recently changed it by adding multiple test cases last month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not where you think it is.

The `for` loop correctly exits.

The output you show is from test case 1 (lines 1 to 6):

> **Input:** nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0], m = 3, nums2 = [2,5,6], n = 3

> ```
> nums1[5] = 6
> nums1[4] = 5
> nums1[3] = 3
> nums1[2] = 2
> nums1[1] = 2
> nums1[0] = 1
> ```

and from test case 2 (line 7):

> **Input:** nums1 = [1], m = 1, nums2 = [], n = 0

> ```
> nums1[0] = 1
> ```

and then your code fails for test case 3

> **Input:** nums1 = [0], m = 0, nums2 = [1], n = 1

---

You can verify that the for loop correctly exits by adding a System.out.println("Done"); after the for loop.

Comment: @JediMasta if updated my answer with the last sentence from my comment (about adding `System.out.println("Done");`)

Comment: I will keep this in mine from now on! Thank you so much!!! Been starting at this problem for almost an hour. LeetCode really needs to update their UI imo.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    for (int i=6; i>-1; i--)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

}